# Is there a way with GRPC to notify the stream of CRUD operations to give realtime updates to the client?

Tags: postgresql, go, grpc

I am new to GRPC and I am trying to implement a basic CRUD + listing. I use unary rpc's for the CRUD and a server stream for the listing. What I would like to do however is update the client whenever someone changes a record in the database that you are listing.

So for example user A is listing 10 companies. And user B is updating one of those companies. I want user A's client to be updated once the update rpc is called.

This is what I have for now

```
func RegisterCompanyServer(l hclog.Logger, gs *grpc.Server) {
    r := postgres.NewPostgresCompanyRepository()
    cs := NewCompanyServer(l, r)
    pb.RegisterCompanyServiceServer(gs, cs)
}

type CompanyServer struct {
    logger hclog.Logger
    repo   repo.CompanyRepository
    pb.UnimplementedCompanyServiceServer
}

func NewCompanyServer(l hclog.Logger, r repo.CompanyRepository) *CompanyServer {
    return &CompanyServer{
        logger: l,
        repo:   r,
    }
}

func (c *CompanyServer) ListCompany(req *pb.CompanyListRequest, stream pb.CompanyService_ListCompanyServer) error {

    //Somehow listen to CreateCompany() and update the client

    companies, err := c.repo.List(req.Query)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for _, c := range companies {

        bytes, err := json.Marshal(c)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        out := &pb.Company{}
        if err = jsonEnc.Unmarshal(bytes, out); err != nil {
            return err
        }

        res := &pb.CompanyListResponse{
            Company: out,
        }

        err = stream.Send(res)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func (c *CompanyServer) CreateCompany(context context.Context, req *pb.CompanyCreateRequest) (*pb.CompanyCreateResponse, error) {
    input := req.GetCompany()

    if input == nil {
        return nil, errors.New("Parsing Error")
    }

    bytes, err := jsonEnc.Marshal(input)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    company := &myCompany.Company{}
    if err = json.Unmarshal(bytes, company); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    result, err := c.repo.Create(company)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    res := &pb.CompanyCreateResponse{
        Id: result,
    }

    //Somehow notify the stream that a company was created

    return res, nil
}
```

Is this even feasable with GRPC? What techniques are out there to do this? I am currently working with a postgresql database.

Comment: you should look into grpc and bidirectional streaming https://grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/core-concepts/ . gRPC does not that "for you" but you can easily implement that sort of notification system using bidirectional streaming server.

Comment: it's a bidirectional gRPC streaming server which works with multi clients: each single client must be registered on the server side and it should be notified when there's an operation which matches with the rules in place.

Comment: I think use MQ and server stream is a good way to do that.

Comment: @HelloWood what is MQ?

Comment: You can reference https://rocketmq.apache.org/docs/quick-start/

Comment: I am unfamiliar with brokers but I found this https://github.com/micro/micro which I am going to implement which has a broker service. It might be what I need. But currently researching.